# How can I interpret "from" in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a question about "from across the street" in the following quote:

> Should he really send in his explanation? He wondered about it. If nobody believed him, and in this case that would be understandable, he could bring Mrs. Grubach in as a witness, or even the old pair **from across the street**, who probably even now were on their way over to the window opposite.
>
> (*The Trial*, Franz Kafka)

I think two interpretations are possible.

The first one is "bring A from B" as in "I brought this book from the shelf."

The second one is "bring A, which is situated across the street."

But I think the second one is more natural here because the sentence is not about yanking this old couple from their house.

I think it is more like, "a man from America."

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: The issue is quite simple: "from" here indicates the place where people are. As you said.. A man from America.. Or a man from across the street.

Answer (score 1):

*from across the street* here refers to the old pair *living across the street* that is **on the other side of the street** probably with respect to Mrs. Grubach.

**from** here is used to indicate a place where they are located.

Answer (score -1):

From means provenance as in a place. The "old pair from across the street" means the elderly couple who live in the house on the other side of the street.

Comment: Let's make this point clear. I don't agree with your points A and B ( which are a bit confused actually) I and KCH explained clearly  what "from" means in this sentence. It does not indicates movenent, but only a state.. The state of being on the other side of the street.